# wall post (feed) on users friends wall is not showing properly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I had made a facebook tab which post on user's friends wall (feed).

Using following code:

```
$facebook->api
                (
                    '/'.$sendTo.'/feed/',
                    'post',
                    array('access_token' => $facebook->access_token,
                    'message' => ''.$send_service ,
                    'name' => 'She\'s got ****\'s Skin!',
                    'description' => ''.$nam1.' has nominated you to be a Pond\'s girl :)  Do return the favor :) ',                    
                    'picture' => 'http://www.mydomain.com/fb_tabs/ponds/rec/images/ponds.png',
                    'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_[app_id]',
                    'auto_publish' => false,
                    'target_id' => '$tag'
                    )
```

It was showing the post as I wanted. Here is the example:
[View Images](http://windchimes.co.in/fb_tabs/sank_test/wallpost/images/img1.png)

Please ignore the blue box in the image.

**But for the last two days, it is commming like this:** [View Image](http://windchimes.co.in/fb_tabs/sank_test/wallpost/images/img2.png)

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Sankalp I'm not able to understand the exact issue you face, can you please explain it again in detail.

Comment: when i made the app it was working fine as I want it to work, and the posts that are going on users wall were as shown in [link](http://windchimes.co.in/fb_tabs/sank_test/wallpost/images/img1.png)image.

but from last two days the wall posts are looking like [link](http://windchimes.co.in/fb_tabs/sank_test/wallpost/images/img2.png)Image2

Now what I want to know that how this is possible or where I am going wrong coz. I had not changed the code at all. its the same as the previous one. how the wall posts got altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need not have to worry about it because facebook also changes in it layout sometime so it will look like that.

You cant do anything in that because things are in not your hand.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But what reason should i put forward to my seniors. Do you have any idea why these changes occurred. Even if facebook changed its layout, when will it get back to its original form and my post will start looking the way they has to..

Comment: See one thing you don't have any control to design your post in facebook. you can do one thing if your post not look nice you can set image height and width. your senior will also understand this. dnt wry.